# Determinant and linear dependence

Tags: determinant, inverse

I understood that if $2$ or more rows or columns in matrix are linear dependent, the determinante is $0$ and it will, seen as a linear transformation, “squeeze” down the room to a space with a smaller dimension (so if I would apply this linear transformation to a 2D space, it will sqeeze it down to a 1D space).

Now because of that this linear transformation(or matrix) can't have an inverse am I right?

Now my question is if I got a matrix and I know, that there is no inverse for it, does this imply that the determinant is $0$?

Comment: I hope you understood what I meant my english skills aren't that great. Please feel free to edit this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for both questions. In particular, the determinant of a (square) matrix is $0$ if and only if the matrix has no inverse.

Comment: So a "zero-determinant" matrix implies not having an inverse and not having an inverse to that matrix implies that the determinant is zero. So it is an equivalence ? Thank you very much :)